# Is it correct to use “to” in “recommend to me studying”?

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I am writing this to my manager.

I’ve found a new job, and I won't start working there for two months.

> I would like to ask you if you recommend **to** me studying specific things, so that when I start working I will already know them.

Is it correct to use “to” in this context?

Comment: It is not incorrect, but it isn't necessary. See [here](http://folk.uio.no/hhasselg/terms.html#indirect_object) the description of what an indirect object is.

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56993/recommend-you-do-something-or-recommend-you-to-do-something

Answer (score 2):

Your instincts are correct; the preposition sounds a little awkward there. I would suggest one of these two alternatives:

> Do you have any recommendations about specific things to study?

or:

> Are there any specific things that you would recommend for me to study?